# Responsive CSS image doesn't match on devices

Tags: css, responsive

I wanted to make responsive website, and I used media query.

One thing I don't understand is, iPhone 6 and LG G5 has different image size. What I figured out is many android device's image size is same.

Is this about IOS and Android problem? or my codding is wrong?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .btn{
        width:70px;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 764px) {
    .btn{
        width:50px;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 364px) {
    .btn{
        width:40px;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: the px sizes are different even though they look the same size to us.

Comment: have a look at here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: That's because the pixel ratio, retina and stuff, Read more about [pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with
I phone 6 media Query

```
@media (max-width:667px){ /* do something here */ } /*landscape view*/

@media (max-width:375px){ /* do something here */ } /*portrait view*/
```